# CSS positioning. Moving header higher

Tags: html, css

[image]Here is my HTML and CSS file:   I am trying to figure out how to move all my headers including the form and button towards more to the middle of the page. Right now they're all at the bottom. I have posted it on codepen (https://codepen.io/tuhmatyow/pen/xLjEqv) but it looks weird because I am using material.io. Here is the screenshot of how it actually looks.

```
<title="Action Auctions"></title>
<body>
<center>
    <h1 class="title">Action Auctions</h1>
    <div class="triangle1"></div>
    <div class="triangle2"></div>
    <h1 class="congratulations">Congrats! You won!</h1>
    <h1 class="but">BUT...</h1>

    <h2 class="donateEarnings">You can still donate your earnings!</h2>
    <form action="/winner/" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ donate_form }}
        <!-- <input type="submit" value="DONATE!"> -->
        <button button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">Donate</button>
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <h3 class="transfer">...or have them transferred to your card</h3>
    <form action="/winner/" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ reimburse_form }}
        <!-- <input type="submit" value="Receive Earnings"> -->
        <button button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">Receive Earnings</button>
    </form>

    <nav class="fixed-nav-bar-bottom">
        <h3 class="copyright">Copyright 2017 ©</h3>
    </nav>
</center>
</body>
```

---

```
 body {
      background-color: #1F2831;
      position: fixed;
    }

    .title {
      color: #FFFFFF;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        padding-top: 30px;
        width: 10em;
        /*overflow: hidden;*/
        letter-spacing: .15em;
        /*text-align: center;*/
        /*white-space: nowrap;*/
        /*margin: 0 auto;*/
    }

    .triangle1 {
        width: 0;
        /*height: 0;*/
        top: -80px;
        right: 145px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 100px 50px 0 50px;
        border-color: #8aa0b8 transparent transparent transparent;
        position: relative;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .triangle2 {
        width: 0;
        /*height: 0;*/
        top: -150px;
        left: 130px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 50px 0 50px 100px;
        border-color: transparent transparent transparent #f59d3f;
        position: relative;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .congratulations {
      color: #FFFFFF;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
      font-size: 30px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .but {
      color: #FFFFFF;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
      font-size: 30px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .form-control {
        height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: #1F2831;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }

    .donateEarnings {
      color: #FFFFFF;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
      font-size: 30px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .transfer {
      color: #FFFFFF;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
      font-size: 30px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .copyright {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }

    .fixed-nav-bar-bottom {
        /*top: 0;*/
        /*left: 0;*/
        bottom: 0;
        height: 10%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: #39678E;
    }
```

Comment: Your triangle `div`s occupy a lot of space below them unnecessarily. Also, your `h1` and `body` margins have not been reset.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to figure out how I can have my triangle not occupy too much space. Do you have nay suggestions? Also, what do you mean by body margins have not been reset? thanks

Comment: Your triangles are set to `position: relative` I am sure you can create the same effect in cleaner way but if you insist on using `position` then set the triangles to `position:absolute` and change their parent container - `<center>` -  to `position:relative`. You can then re-position them to where you want using `top` and `left`. As far as the margins. Every browser has default display properties for certain html elements. `<h1>` elements by default have a lot of margin added to them unless you overwrite the defaults by declaring your own values. Same applies to <`body>`

Comment: Not related to your problem, but there is no `<center>` tag in HTML5. Kill that and just put `text-align: center;` in your `body { }` rules in the stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your triangle classes are set to "display:relative" which means they are stacking...  You corrected for that by giving negative values to each triangle's "top" positions. This basically made the body element stretch for each triangle and for each you simply positioned each triangle vertically out and above the element container they were within.

Make each triangle's class "position:fixed" and adjust your top/left/right to put your triangles where you want.

Maybe something like this:

```
.triangle1 {
    width: 0;
    /*height: 0;*/
    top: 25px;
    left: 90px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 100px 50px 0 50px;
    border-color: #8aa0b8 transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

.triangle2 {
    width: 0;
    /*height: 0;*/
    top: 50px;
    left: 130px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 50px 0 50px 100px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #f59d3f;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

.center{
    position:relative;
    display: block;
}
```

And add class "center" to your center element:

```
<center class="center">
```

> This is where @i-haz-kode  was going in his/her comment above.

Comment: It sorta works. But the problem is that when I resize the browser the triangles spread out and doesn't stay w/in the title.

Comment: Edited my answer.